# Excel VBA: protect cells without locking sheet

Tags: excel

Is it possible to protect cells with following options **without locking worksheet**:

```
    DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, 
    AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, 
    AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True 
    .EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
```

It's Excel VBA.

Thank you.

Comment: You can set the `Locked` and `Hidden` property for each cell. Yet, they get only enforced if the sheet is protected. So, no it is not possible to protect cells without protecting the sheet. Maybe - if you elaborate why you don't want to implement a sheet protection - we can try to find a workaround?

Comment: You want to lock the door without closing it?

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to protect sheet because then appears other problems (Excel freeze) and so on, sometimes.